# What is the proper way to add two covariates in the level 2 of a HLM via lme4?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, growth-mixture-model

### I am currently doing a study examining on how the outcome variable Y changed over time, and I want to control two time-invariant (gender and ageL2) variables in my model. But I am not sure about adding the "Cov*Time" item

Hopefully, the formula should be like`lmer(Y~Time+gender+ageL2+(Time|id)`.

---

But when reading a similar journal article (they had one time-invariant covariate in the level2), I found they made the lme4 like this`lmer(Y~Time+Cov+Cov*Time+(Time|id)`

So, I was wondering why a time-invariant variable should have an interaction with Time? Should I include an `Cov*Time`in my formula and use `lmer(Y~Time+Gender+ageL2+Gender*Time+ageL2*Time+(Time|id)`?
If I am correct, under such condition, the Level2 equations will be like:`β0i = γ00 + γ01 * Gender1i + γ02 * ageL22i + u0i`
and `β1i = γ10 + γ11 * Gender1i + γ12 * ageL22i + u1i`

So, how should the results be interpreted? what do γ00, γ01, γ02, γ10, γ11 and γ12 mean? I suppose the interpretation of these are pretty different

---

Answer (score 0):

An interaction between `Cov` and `Time` means that the relationship between `Cov` and `Y` changes across time. It doesn't mean that the value of `Cov` for each person has to change across time. For example, maybe having a gene for high cholesterol (`Cov`) doesn't have a strong relationship with risk of heart attack (`Y`) when someone is young, but it does have a strong relationship when someone is old. This is a time-varying effect of a time-invariant predictor.

Whether you should include a term like this in your model depends is a substantive question. You are essentially asking "what is the right model?". We don't know what the right model is, which is why we do statistics in the first place. You can always include it and see if the coefficient is different from 0, but whether it is or isn't might not mean anything substantively (e.g., if the variable is confounded or mediated, in which case the coefficient may not represent a meaningful effect).

Comment: Thank you very much for the illuminating answer! I found that the confounding effect you mentioned is indeed very possible in my model. Because if I did not add the interaction between covariates and time, the fixed time effect is non-significant, however, when the interaction between covariates and time was added, the time effect on Y became significant (but the effect size is very small with beta=0.08, p<.05).